# How to get a debug view in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, eclipse-plugin

If I want to get a view by entering the ID using this code,so from where I can get the MyView.ID?

```
IViewPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
        .findView(MyView.ID);
    if (part instanceof MyView) {
        MyView view = (MyView) part;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either find the plugin that contributes the view and look in its 'plugin.xml' to find the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point that defines the view.

Or you can use the Eclipse [plugin spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) tool to identify the view.

Debug has many views so I'm not sure which one you are asking about. The one labelled 'Debug' has id `org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView`

Comment: what's the difference between MyView and MyView.ID

Comment: The `findView` parameter is a string containing the view id. The returned object will be a class implementing `IViewPart` which you can cast to the actual view class if you know what it is. `MyView.ID` and `MyView` are just example names.

Comment: and how I can know the class of the actual view?

Comment: for example if I want to read the contents of the debug View and the ID is org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView , how to know the class?

Comment: Plugin spy will tell you or you look at the plugin's plugin.xml. However for `org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView` the class is `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.launch.LaunchView` which is an **internal** class. You must **not** use internal classes [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). The debug system provides plenty of extension points which provide a much better way to get information.

Comment: thx :-) and How I can show a view with code  that exist but doesn't appear in the tool bar but I have her ID?

Comment: IWorkbenchPage workbenchPage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
   workbenchPage.showView("org.eclipse.tcf.TraceView");

Comment: Comments are not for debugging. Ask a new question. And accept this answer.